Power BI Table vis incorrectly creating multiple rows per dimension value
In my Power BI Model I have ItemStoreOuts table which has items and stores and various facts. This table connects to the Product table and ProductKey and the Store table on RetailKey.
Product and Store tables join to DepotAlignment table on ProductKey and RetailKey (each is a one-to-many relationship).
DepotAlignment table has a DepotKey according to the ProductKey and RetailKey combination.
DepotAlignment table then connects to the Depot table on this DepotKey (many-to-one relationship). Depot table has DepotKey and the DepotName.
Depot then connects to DepotInventory on the DepotKey (one-to-many). DepotInventory has DepotKey, ProductKey and fact column DepotUnits.
The Product table also then connects to the DepotInventory table on ProductKey.
In my table visualisation, I have one particular Item and the Stores (that that item sells in) as the two dimension tables in this table visualisation.
I can then bring various facts into this table and it works as expected. The problem I have starts when I bring the DepotName field into the table visualisation.
I am expecting that one row of this table (i.e. one item in one store) has only one DepotName associated with it. As soon as I bring DepotName into the visualisation, it creates multiple rows for each items store, each row for a different DepotName, even though there should only be one DepotName per Item-Store.
If I remove DepotName everything seems fine. Even if I introduce the field DepotUnits, from DepotInventory, everything still seems fine.
The problem seems specific to when I bring the DepotName field into my visualisation, along with a calculated field... either of these on their own work fine but not both together. 
This is fine:
This, when I bring in the calculated field "SalesWTD-VTP-Outs = SUM(ItemStoreOuts[WTDSales]) - SUM(ItemStoreOuts[WTDFcast])" ... is now not fine. I get all the Depots against each Item-Store.

